# Upload image to S3 be error SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to upload image into S3, image will be uploaded from FrontEnd and store image path into database via API, for security, I don't want config aws private key on FrontEnd, then I create a new API to generate a presigned url and return for FE can upload image to it. PresignedUrl is worked, but when I tried to upload to it, AWS service return error SignatureDoesNotMatch. Please take a look my code:

```
exports.getPresignedUrlService = async () => {
  aws.config.update({
    region: 'ap-southeast-1',
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_PUBLIC_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_PRIVATE_KEY,
  });

  const S3 = new aws.S3;
  const signedUrl = await S3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
    Bucket: 'event-images',
    Key: 'events/test.png',
    Expires: 5 * 60,
    ContentType: 'image/*',
  });

  const image = fs.readFileSync('/event-logging-uml.png');

  const res = await axios.put(decodeURIComponent(signedUrl), image, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'image/png',
    },
  });

  return {
    status: 200,
    data: decodeURIComponent(signedUrl),
  };
};
```

Here is function to generate preSignedUrl and return for FE, but I want to test to make sure the url is correct, so I read file from local computer and put that image to generated url earlier. But it's not worked,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n' +
      '<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>*******</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>
```

I tried put an object without presigned url to make sure my public key have permission to upload a file by command cli:

```
aws s3 cp event-logging-uml.png s3://event-images/test
```

It's worked and file is uploaded.

Please drop the comment if did you faced with this issue before or have any way to fix it